# Does the closure of a function include the actual parameter passed to the function?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, semantics

A closure of a function includes the environment when calling the function.

Does the environment included in a closure of a function include the actual parameters for the function?

If I am correct, from mathematical logic point of view, a closure for an expression consists of the free variables of the expression. So I guess the answer to the question is no.

Answer (score 5):

No. A closure is a function, and, as such, its parameters are passed when the function is called. The main difference between *closures* and *plain functions* is that closures are associated with an environment. This environment stores the values of the free variables* that were in scope when the function was created.

* The term *free variable* refers to those variables which are used locally within a function but are defined outside of this function (i.e., in an enclosing scope).